# Wpf listview disable selection but allow clicking

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, wpf-listview

I have a simple listview bound to data with caliburn micro. When i click an item an event happens but othe item gets the blue selection and unable to click it again (without clicking elsewhere then on it again).
How can i allow selecting the same item twice without having to select another item first?

Note: All other questions on SO seem to answer how to remove the blue highlight, but my issue is with the behaviour not the style

Comment: Could you post sample of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of MouseLeftButtonUp event. For example,

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" x:Name="MyListView" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp]=[Action OnClick($this)]"  />
```

And in View Model

```
 public void OnClick(object item)
 {
       if (item == null) return;
            // do something
 }
```